# How to do customization in Visual Studio Editor

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

First I say how acts visual studio: for example when you add a div element to a Html or asp page and then in the design view try to change its dimension (for example making it longer) it do it by changing html code, not by css, for example adds blank spaces to enlarge the div. I want to have a component that is a combination of html, javascript and css which act together. When I change it in design mode it changes the css and javascript. I think it will be useful to be able to receive the events from the editor (for example on enlarging the div) and acts on the event. Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default HTML editor in Visual Studio to Web Forms

- Go to `File` > `New` > `File`
- Select **HTML Page**
- In the lower right corner of the New File dialog there is a **drop down arrow** on the **Open button**
- Click the arrow to see **Open With**
- Select **HTML (Web Forms) Editor**
- Click **Set as Default**
- Press **OK**

After that, HTML files will be opened in Web Forms Editor by default and you will see `Design • Split • Source` on the bottom of the editor. **In Design View you can simply edit HTML with no coding required.**

> [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z74w20y(v=vs.110).aspx) is a simple intro to Web Forms Editor and how Visual Studio handles CSS and other style elements. **No universal component which will allow you to change `div` size by typing spaces into it.**